# This gradle plugin requires Android Studio 3.0 minimum

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-studio-3.0

I am getting mentioned error when importing this project: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare.

Comment: Go download it then...

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't know there is a preview version (3.0 Canary 7) for the android studio. Well downloaded it, the app is working.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue, replace in build.gradle your classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:apla3XX.XX' by classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3' to downgrade your graddle.

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/294

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution is to download Android 3.0 but if you don't want to use beta version you can change the gradle version to whichever version you prefer. To change version follow these steps

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> change gradle version to 3.3 and android plugin version to the android studio version you are using. -> Rebuild your project.

[image]