# How to resolve Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am getting `Error:This Gradle plugin requires Studio 3.0 minimum` when importing project
Project repo: https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare
I had tried mentioned solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45171647/this-gradle-plugin-requires-android-studio-3-0-minimum) and [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwisp_zRlL7VAhUIK48KHd8wAtgQFgglMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffirebase%2Fquickstart-android%2Fissues%2F294&usg=AFQjCNEGCb1q0tySOWAbyhcPw-1Fm-lAuA) but nothing worked :(

Comment: So which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: Try converting [this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L6) line to `distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip`

Comment: @EdmundJohnson Android Studio 2.3.2

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The repository you're trying to import uses gradle build tools 3.0.0 and gradle 4.0. These aren't supported in Android Studio 2.3, which means that project can only be opened in Android Studio 3.0 preview.

Your options:

1) [Download android studio 3.0 preview](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html) and use it for the project

2) Check out repository and revert it to just before [commit 822b84a1e58126412f708745d8bcee5a525620ae](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare/commit/822b84a1e58126412f708745d8bcee5a525620ae) (which is where the conversion to latest version of gradle happened)

Comment: I tried the second solution but it didn't work it still searching for gradle build 3.0, the Only solution left is to use Android Studio 3.0

Comment: @VaibhavSingh I think the problem is that you are trying to revert to the commit where the update happened, not before it. Please make sure you're reverting to *before* the commit that I've linked to

Comment: Updating Studio fixed my problem.

Answer (score 16):

Option #1: Do not attempt to import the project until you upgrade to Android Studio 3.0

Option #2: Modify the project:

- Change the project-level `build.gradle` to refer to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3` instead of `com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha6`
- Change `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` to refer to `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip` instead of `https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-milestone-1-all.zip`
- Import the project and pray that its author is not depending on things that you changed

Comment: After changing your suggestions, Now I am getting `GradleError:(25, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'`

Comment: @VaibhavSingh: That project relies upon the newer Gradle and Android Plugin for Gradle, so fixing up the project is not going to be easy. Either use Android Studio 3.0 or follow Oleg's recommendation of using an older version of that app, before the change to require these newer tools.

Answer (score 8):

replace

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha4'
```

with

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

in the projects build.gradle files.

Answer (score 7):

this Error occurs when you are trying to import Project which is created **in studio 3.0 and above** into **Android Studio 2.3.3 or below**. make following changes to work in Studio below 3

**1)in Project gradle add below configuration:**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

**2) in App (or module) gradle file**

remove following lines if there are any

```
compileOptions {
    targetCompatibility 1.8
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
}
```

and change all **implementation and annotationProcessor** in dependency **to compile** like below

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'   
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0'
implementation 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9-1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9-1'
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
```

}

**To**

```
dependencies {
//implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.0'
compile 'android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0-alpha9-1'
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
compile 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0-alpha9-1'
compile "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0-alpha9-1"
compile 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.2'
```

}

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue, it can be resolved by changing the gradle and android plugin version using following steps.

File -> Project Structure -> Project -> change gradle version to 3.3 and android plugin version to the android studio version you are using. -> Rebuild your project.

[image]

It may give some error for methods which were not in previous gradle versions. One that you mentioned in one of your comment *GradleError:(25, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'implementation()'* can be resolved by replacing implementation by compile.

May be you have resolved you issue but may help others.

Answer (score 2):

Once I downloaded the project  created in Android Studio v3 and I had v2.3.3. So when I tried to launch the project there were some incompatibility issues. And for those who faced the same problem the solution is the following:
1.  Go to File=> Project Structure=> Project and change Gradle version to 3.3 and Android Plugin version to 2.3.3
2.  In CinemaProject build.gradle file:
2.1.    Delete "google()" methods wherever you see it in the file
2.2.    Change allprojects section in the file  like that:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

3. In app build.gradle file :
   Add buildToolsVersion "26.0.0" in android {} section  after compileSdkVersion

Change the following

```
dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'


        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'


        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
        compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'


        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

Like that

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'

    testCompile  'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: see the solution or problem]hi guys i solve this issue i want to explain you you check your android studio ide version first this is the reason if you using ide 1.5 then you cant use gradle version 3.0+.